# Executing vstest.console.exe remotely results in exit code: 559038737

Tags: java, visual-studio, build, msbuild, vstest

We are trying to run unit tests on a remote windows machine by invoking vstest.console.exe from within Java (using Apache's commons library).

During execution, we are seeing the following logs:

```
Command being executed: vstest.console.exe testProject.dll 

-559038737
```

The value "-559038737" is the exit code from the command indicating that it has failed.

"vstest.console.exe testProject.dll " when run directly on the command line executes as expected. We also tried executing the Java command which internally invokes this one and that too worked as expected.

To debug the issue, we've tried the following:

1. Redirecting the stdout and stderr to a file to see if there is some additional information.
2. Increasing the heap size to 1024m.

Neither helped.

What can I try to debug this issue further?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I tried the following:

1. Added the flags: /Platform:x64 /InIsolation /Framework:framework40
2. Started the jnlp launcher (which connects the m/c to the master) with administrator privileges

Leaving this as an unaccepted answer since I'm not sure what actually caused the problem and how it was solved.